# A probability question from sociology

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis

We know that $\frac{1}{2} \leq a \leq p \leq 1$. And, $n \geq 3$ is a positive odd number, and $t$ is an integer. $a$ satisfies the equation below.

\begin{equation} \small
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}  \left(  {n-1 \choose t} [p a^{t} (1-a)^{n-t-1}+(1-p) (1-a)^{t} a^{n-{t}-1}] \cdot [\frac{a^{t+1} (1-a)^{n-t-1}}{a^{t+1} (1-a)^{n-t-1}+(1-a)^{t+1} a^{n-t-1}}-\frac{a^{t} (1-a)^{n-t}}{a^{t} (1-a)^{n-t}+(1-a)^{t} a^{n-t}}]   \right) \\[15pt]
&={n-1 \choose {\frac{n-1}{2}}} a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(1-a)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}  (2p-1)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

We want to prove that $a$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Any references or remarks are appreciated!

Comment: This site is full of questions that are not easy, yet we typically do not offer money for solutions.  Can you give some motivation for this question that is mathematical rather than monetary?  That is, how did this question come up for you?

Comment: Is $t$ fixed as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: It seems the left-hand-side is $p$-independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I expand the left-hand-side of your equation around $a=1/2$ I find
$$
\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}    {n-1 \choose t} [p a^{t} (1-a)^{n-t-1}+(1-p) (1-a)^{t} a^{n-{t}-1}] $$
$$\times\left[\frac{a^{t+1} (1-a)^{n-t-1}}{a^{t+1} (1-a)^{n-t-1}+(1-a)^{t+1} a^{n-t-1}}-\frac{a^{t} (1-a)^{n-t}}{a^{t} (1-a)^{n-t}+(1-a)^{t} a^{n-t}}\right]   $$
$$=\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right) 2^{2-n} \binom{n-1}{t}+{\cal O}(a-1/2)^3=2a-1+{\cal O}(a-1/2)^3.$$
I similarly expand the right-hand-side,
$${n-1 \choose {\frac{n-1}{2}}} a^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(1-a)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}  (2p-1)=2^{1-n} (2 p-1) \binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}-\left(a-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 2^{2-n} (n-1) (2 p-1) \binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}+{\cal O}(a-1/2)^4.$$
Equating left-hand-side and right-hand-side I solve for $a$,
$$a=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2^n \left(\sqrt{2^{3-2 n} (n-1) (1-2 p)^2 q^2+1}-1\right)}{4(n-1) (2 p-1) q},\;\;q=\binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}{2}}.$$
For $n\gg 1$ this solution tends to
$$a\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2n}}\frac{\sqrt{16 (p-1) p+\pi +4}-\sqrt{\pi }}{2 p-1}.$$

Comment: the term $(a-\frac{1}{2}) 2^{2-n} \binom{n-1}{t}$ is the first nonzero term in a Taylor series around $a=1/2$; I then used the identity $\sum _{t=0}^{n-1}  \binom{n-1}{t}=2^{n-1}$ to obtain $2a-1$ for the sum.

Comment: the term of order $(a-1/2)^2$ sums to zero when summed from $t=0$ to $t=n-1$.

Comment: both l.h.s. and r.h.s. are correct up to and including terms of the same order $(a-1/2)^2$. I would hope that makes for a consistent calculation, but I am not certain.